# Matlab reading numbers with higher precision

Tags: matlab

I have made this scripts that calculates the frequency of a given dataset, but matlab is not precise enough, is it possible to make matlab read in more accurat numbers and not cut off the numbers? I want it to use 8 digits (0.12345678) instead of 4 (0.1234) that is does now

```
fid = fopen('forceCoeffs.dat','rt');
A = textscan(fid, '%f%f%f%f%f%f', 'HeaderLines',9,'Collect', 9);
A = A{1};
fclose(fid);

t = A(:,1);

Fs = 1/(A(1,1));
x = A(:,2)

x = detrend(x,0);
xdft = fft(x);
freq = 0:Fs/length(x):Fs/2;
xdft = xdft(1:length(x)/2+1);
plot(freq,abs(xdft));
[~,I] = max(abs(xdft));
fprintf('Maximum occurs at %d Hz.\n',freq(I));
```

File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9CEsYCSSZUSb1JmcHRkbFdWYUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: [`format long`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) ?

Comment: MATLAB uses floating point numbers. It is not rounding anything. If you only have four digits of precision then either thats all that is in the file or you are reading the file wrong. Make sure you are not just looking at what is printed in the console because MATLAB rounds those for easier reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for including the `forceCoeffs.dat` file as it allowed me to run your code. Here is an explanation of what you are seeing.

First I want to point out that MATLAB is not rounding anything. You can check the data type of `A` to ensure you have enough precision.

```
>> class(A)

ans =

double
```

And since you are reading in the file using `%f` for each column, MATLAB will use all the bits provided by the `double` type. Ok, now take a look at the contents of your file. The first column has only 2 decimals of precision at most.

```
0.05            -7.013874e-09   1.410717e+02    -6.688450e-02   -3.344226e-02   -3.344224e-02
...
349.95          -1.189524e-03   1.381022e+00    -2.523909e-01   -1.273850e-01   -1.250059e-01
350             -1.423947e-03   1.380908e+00    -2.471767e-01   -1.250123e-01   -1.221644e-01
```

Since no more is needed MATLAB only prints four decimal places when you look at the variable in the variable explorer. Try looking at one of the other columns to see what I am talking about. I commented out the `A = A{1}` part of your code and looked at the second column. When clicking on the number you see the full precision.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a long type to display 16 digits

Answer (score 0):

To get more than 4 digits precision, you can use

```
format long
```

However, to get exactly 8 digits, you need to round it. If your number is `a` then let use:

```
format long
round(1e8*a)*1e-8
```

Comment: I tried to put "format long" on the start of my script, but matlab read my file "forceCoeffs.dat" with only 4 digits precision

Comment: strange, on linux/octave it reads with 15 digits once you set ``format long``

Comment: `format long` only changes what is printed in the console. MATLAB uses floating point numbers - it does not round numbers to four digits.